# How to setup cron job in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cron, email-attachments

I am working on magento 1.7.0.2 version.

I want to send csv in mails to customers.
This should be done every month using cron job in magento.

For cron job config.xml

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <Module_Store>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>clinic/observer::sendMailtoClinic</model></run>
        </Module_Store>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Observer.php

```
class Module_Store_Model_Observer {

  public function sendMailtoClinic(Varien_Event_Observer $observer, $content){                        
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
    $mail->setFrom($from_email, $from_email_name);
    $mail->addTo($to_email, $toEmailName);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($file_path));
    $file->type = 'text/csv';
    $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
    $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $file->filename = $file_name;
    $mail->send();
  }
}
```

Admin configuration for cron are :-

```
Generate Schedules Every 15
Schedule Ahead for 15
Missed if Not Run Within 35
History Cleanup Every 15
Success History Lifetime 10
Failure History Lifetime 600
```

Any help would be much appreciable.

Comment: Now My job is listing in cron_schedule table but all the jobs showing pending status and showing 'created at' and 'scheduled at' timing in database. Waiting from last 1 hour But 'executed at' time shows null.

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct ??

Comment: Yes,Code is correct.When I installed AOE scheduler extension and generate schedule it is working but by default(every 15 min) it is not :( I ran cron.php from browser but no luck

Comment: Can you explain the issue case in bit details?

Comment: cron job not running automatically on localhost

Comment: have you checked magento log file?

Comment: Can you send email from your localhost? do you have smtp enabled and working?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Now to setup Crontab in Magento go to Admin => system => configuration => system => ‘Cron (Scheduled Tasks)’ tab.

Comment: I already do that see my question

Comment: if you want to send mail on localhost for testing, make sure smtp working on your localhost.

Comment: have u set cron.php in your crontab..u can check using crontab -l

Answer (score 5):

If mail system working fine and still you facing issue with this then try this one also:

replace your config code with this:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <clinic_cron>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>clinic/observer::sendMailtoClinic</model></run>
        </clinic_cron>
    </jobs>
</crontab> 


class [Packagename]_Clinic_Model_Observer { // don't forget to mention package name

  public function sendMailtoClinic(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){                        

    $html_body = 'this is html body text';
    $from_email = 'from_email@domain.com';
    $from_email_name = 'sendername';
    $to_email = 'to_email@domain.com';
    $toEmailName = 'receiverName';
    $subject = 'subject text here';
    $file_path = 'here/is/file/path';
    $file_name = 'filename.csv';

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
    $mail->setFrom($from_email, $from_email_name);
    $mail->addTo($to_email, $toEmailName);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($file_path));
    $file->type = 'text/csv';
    $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
    $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $file->filename = $file_name;
    $mail->send();
  }
}
```

search the word "clinic_cron" in Scheduled tasks tasks list here : System > Scheduler > List View. Make sure you are searching with all scheduled tasks, i mean see paging also ;)

Hope this helps! All the best!

Comment: mail system working fine.The only issue is cron is not scheduling automatically on server.I need to schedule and run all cron jobs using AOE scheduler

Comment: did you setting up the Cron on cPanel?

Comment: one more thing, if crontab listed here system > Scheduler > Schedule Configuration, then Schedule that task by selecting action "Schedule now".

Comment: Yes, I am also saying same thinng that using "Schedule now" it is working.But it should be auto start.
Do I add anything for this in c-panel? How I can add ? Can you please explain?

Comment: yes you need to set cronjob in cpanel. see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/cron-job-command-in-cpanel

Answer (score 3):

Got to app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml

and the put

```
   <config>
     ...
   <crontab>
    <jobs>
    <catalogrule_apply_all>
        <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model></run>
    </catalogrule_apply_all>
  </jobs>
    ...
 </crontab>
   ...
  </config>
```

You can change the schedule as per you need for more please see http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Never change the core files.

Answer (score 3):

All code you do is fine you just only need to set cron.php as a cron job on server.

Comment: How can I set it on server?

Comment: Please refer this
https://kayako.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOCS/Setting+up+a+server+cron+or+scheduled+task

Comment: Neeraj, same thing I told you here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709781/how-to-setup-cron-job-in-magento/23781591?noredirect=1#comment36612325_23781591